# Should I have Localizable.strings Base or English?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization

Following Ray Wenderlich tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/180356/ios-internationalization), the `Localizable.strings` is as following. Notice there is no `Localizable.strings(Base)`

[image]

But in some other tutorials, they would use Base instead of English, so did I in my project as follow.

[image]

My iPhone's preferred language order is English then Chinese and is currently set to English. But whenever I run the app, it goes to Chinese except when I explicitly edit scheme to ask Xcode to run it in English. Does that mean I should have `Localizable.strings (English)` instead of `Localizable.strings (Base)`?

Another question, I have `Main.storyboard (Base)` and `Main.strings (Chinese (Simplified))` under `Main.storyboard`. But no matter what I do, the storyboard always shows up in Chinese version. What have I done wrong?

### === Update ===

I played around with it (simply remove and recreate, nothing changed), and then magically the localization works as expected: The app default to English, which is my system language, and switches to Chinese when I edit scheme. However, now my storyboard is stuck with `(Base)` version no matter what I do.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on this, but as I understand the `Base` file is a fallback if your app doesn't have a `Localizable.strings` file for the user's device language.

So if you have English and Chinese as localization files, but your preferred languages are German and Japanese, the system will check the `Base` file for strings.

In your case you have Chinese and the base files. English is not found, so it takes the other preferred language (Chinese). Therefore the base strings are not used -- the app defaults to the Chinese localization.

To solve the problem, you need to make an English strings file in addition to your base strings.